# Is it possible to have a Git repository on a local router with USB drive?

Tags: git, networking, router, nas, fritzbox

I have a router (AVM Fritzbox) with a USB drive connected to it. I can access the drive via a network path from my computers. I only have access to the web interface of the router and the filesystem of the drive. No root or ssh access (I don't want it anyways because if I screw up anything I can't access internet or phone anymore).

Is it possible that this drive acts as a Git repository without Git being installed on the router itself so that I can access the repository from all computers that are connected to the router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how your "network path" actually works (though it sounds like Samba, or some other zeroconf protocol).

Git can only operate with HTTP(S) and SSH protocols as transports, unless you configure one of those properly, you can't use git on your router as a remote.

Read http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols for more info. (Also, this question has sort-of been answered before [Using Git with a Samba shared folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23109918/using-git-with-a-samba-shared-folder)).

Comment: Thanks, seems I won' be able to use my router as a repository then. There's no git installed on the router anyways. I hoped that it'd be possible to store the source files and the git files on the router drive, but have the git on my computers control them remotely.

Comment: @FooBar if you're really into this, and your device is supported, see if installing OpenWrt on it is something you'd like to do http://openwrt.org/

Comment: For my router there is indeed a modded firmware available, but I don't want to risk damage (it's my only router and I need it for all internet and phone access). I think I'll simply invest in a Raspberry Pi or sth. similar.